# recyling bitmaps in OnDestroy - 'trying to use a recycled bitmap' when relaunching activity

Tags: android

I have two simple activities `A` and `B`. The user starts `B` from `A` by pressing a button, and the user then returns to `A` by pressing the back button.

In the `onDestroy()` method of activity `B` I recycle some background images used in activity `B`. What I am trying to understand is why, when activity `B` is started again, I am getting 'trying to use a recycled bitmap'. Surely the bitmaps will be loaded again in the onCreate() method? like they must have been on the first time the activity was launched.

Here is my example code:

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity {

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);    
         setContentView(R.layout.selectionpage);    
     }  

     @Override
     public void onDestroy() {      
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        ((BitmapDrawable)iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap().recycle();
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
        ((BitmapDrawable)ll.getBackground()).getBitmap().recycle();
        super.onDestroy();
     }
 }
```

The code I use to launch activity `B` from `A`

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
     startActivity(intent);
```

selectionpage.XML :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/backgroundimage">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/selectionimage"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

This part may be relevant. I'm not sure. I've noticed that after launching activity B, even after it has been destroyed, I can still see an instance of my activity when analyzing the memory heap using MAT. The path to GC roots seems to go through Java.lang.Thread and ContextImpl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get that error because `ImageView iv` & `LinearLayout ll` are still pointing to recycled bitmaps. You don't need to do recycling yourself inside `onDestroy()`. Bitmaps will be freed when they are not needed by the system.

Comment: Yup. I'm an idiot - I didn't realize that's how the xml files work. Though one thing I did notice is that in another area of my program I seem to be getting out of memory errors after loading several large images. Even though some of the images aren't going to be used anymore, the GC doesn't seem to want to remove them. I'm having to call recycle() on those - I believe to notify the GC to clean them up right away rather than wait for a while. Anyway, I'm rambling. Thanks for your answer

Comment: This is not true for all version of android : `On Android 2.3.3 (API level 10) and lower, the backing pixel data for a bitmap is stored in native memory. It is separate from the bitmap itself, which is stored in the Dalvik heap. The pixel data in native memory is not released in a predictable manner, potentially causing an application to briefly exceed its memory limits and crash` http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html#inBitmap

Answer (score 1):

You may have a memory leak if you have a reference to the activity in a separate thread which is retaining the activity for longer than it should.

This could cause iv and ll from the old activity to still be using the bitmaps after they're recycled. You could do iv.setImageDrawable(null) and ll.setBackgroundDrawable(null), but these bitmaps are created by the system and you shouldn't need to recycle them.

I am guessing that you're trying to recycle them because you ran into memory issues? which would be better explained by the possible above mentioned leak.

Comment: I do have memory issues you are right. I've searched high and low and cannot find any references that might cause this activity to have memory leak. I was trying to recycle because I cannot understand why that when I start activity B I lose 3Mb of heap space. When I close the activity I don't seem to get it back. When I relaunch the activity, the heap only increases by a few kbs. As I say, I have looked into the memory dump and can see the activity seems to still exist, but no matter how many times I stop/start the activity it is still only 1 copy

Comment: What are you doing in B - do you have any threads or async tasks? do you have any inner classes? do you set something like a drawable or view to a static variable? do you retain the instance of the activity at all?

Comment: I believe my problem in B is with AdMob (I have a banner ad). I have tried removing AdMob and everything seems to clear up nicely. I think adMob is taking my context and not destroying itself, thus stopping anything else from being cleaned.

Answer (score -1):

You must do it in code.
Do initiate Bitmap object in code and use Imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap)

```
Bitmap bitmap;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.selectionpage);   
     bitmap = new BitmapFactory.decode...
     yourImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

 }  
 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {      

    super.onDestroy();
    // do recycle bitmap here
    bitmap.recycle();
 }
```

Comment: This code has high chance raising: FATAL EXCEPTION: java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@410a9720 which means recycle was called too early while a canvas was still using it.